# Selenium Remote Webdriver insane memory usage

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I've created a small python script to run tests over around 40 pages of a small database driven site.

I'm using selenium remove webdriver initialised wtih driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)

It takes a minute or 2 to run and I noticed my laptop grinding to a hault when I looked in system monitor java was taking up 1.7gb of memory and my processor was at 100%.

The selenium documentation makes a vague reference to logs being cleared on stop or driver session end but I cant work like this its ridiculous.

I'm starting the server from terminal with java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar

Does anyone have any idea what I've done wrong or is this how selenium works?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included teardown methods? Yes Selenium is memory intensive but 1.7 gb is ridiculous. If you're not doing any teardown methods then you're grinding your memory through having many browser windows open

Comment: What happens if you try a different Browser, one that isn't the HtmlUnit browser? Have you tried it on a different machine? 1.7GB is not correct, so something has obviously gone wrong. With that said, thousands use the HtmlUnit driver within Selenium, so there will be more to play than just simply "Selenium is broken."

Comment: Can't speak for HtmlUnit, but I have myself seen IE (8/9) leak memory in bucket loads reaching 1.5GB+ within minutes of intensive webdriver activity on a "Rich" HTML page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replys. Hmmm.. errr... teardown methods? I'm just initialising the driver using driver.get() and then driver.close() and driver.quit() at the end of the script.

Comment: I have the same issue, just running one, simple, lettuce tests chomps through 1GB of ram immediatly. If I leave the server running inbetween running this test 10-20 times, it's eaten all of my (4GB) ram and starts swapping. This causes my music to skip and me to post on SO.

Comment: Additionally, this is a recent thing, I ran the same environment (ubuntu: lettuce-webdriver testing a django app with selenium on the standalone server) in Febuary and it worked fine. [java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar]